# Django: Class based view instantiated for each request, is it efficient?

Tags: django

From Django documentation:

> While your class is instantiated for each request dispatched to it,
>   class attributes set through the as_view() entry point are configured
>   only once at the time your URLs are imported.

Will it not be inefficient to instantiate view per request considering heavy concurrent traffic ?

Comment: Only way to know: performance test your app. Apparently, though, the Django authors considered the benefits of throwing the entire state away worth any overhead incurred by re-instantiating the object. If constructing the object is fairly cheap, that may not be much overhead at all, and it might be less overhead than trying to clear out any state, which is also more error prone. Whether that's good enough for your app depends on your performance needs and how you're using it and how they're doing it. For most apps, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the comment from jpmc26 I would guess its not a big problem. If you follow the workflow Django is doing from when a request is coming in until the response is rendered, there are way more steps involved which initiate objects. The class-based view is probably the least of the problem, assuming you didn't implement it to be blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think memory would be an issue (if you had been talking about time taken, you might have had an argument, but see jpmc26's comment).

Python's memory allocation/deallocation is done by means of reference counting, not timed garbage collection. As soon as an object goes out of scope, assuming it has no circular references, it is destroyed. So if the server has enough memory to serve the request and allocate the object in the first place, there's no danger of it hanging around past its useful lifetime.